# how to use regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

```
replace(/(?<=<\?php)[\w\W]*(?=\?>)/g, " ");
```

I want to replace the words between `<?php` and `?>`, but it doesn't work in JavaScript.
I have heard that JavaScript doesn't support regular expressions. How else can I solve this problem?

Comment: Whoever told you that JavaScript doesn't support regular expressions is sorely misinformed.

Comment: Why do you have text between `<?php ?>` that is available to JavaScript? Hopefully it has not been sent down to the client.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds (the `(?<=` part) in regular expressions. You can just replace it with `<?php ?>` and drop the assertions, though:

```
replace(/<\?php.+?\?>/g, "<?php ?>");
```

Comment: @final. If it helped you, don't forget to click on the check sign on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look behinds and look aheads do not work instead rewrite your regex.

```
replace(/(<\?php)([\w\W]*)(\?>)/g, "$1$3")
```